# why does Acer Aspire E5-571 V1.26 hang and freeze and startup slow and shut down slow?

Tags: boot, laptop, performance, freeze, shutdown

I own a Acer Aspire E5-571 V1.26 notebook Windows 8. and I have had trouble with it off and on since I bought it. It would freeze up and hang when software was clicked on to open. escape key didn't work or task manager so I would cold boot it often. Put windows 10 upgrade in it three times  and it still hangs up and freezes randomly. Good little computer otherwise. It is just frustrating. I am 85 and wife 78, not good for old brain. Limited software is downloaded. I have Wise Care 365 Pro, Malwarebytes Pro and windows defender. It is faster starting up now since wife went into registry and changed shutdown and start up values but it still freezes up and hangs randomly.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.